# Make a javascript canvas rectangle clickable

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am creating a simple calculator. [Here](http://startupsandfinance.com/online_calculator.html) it is. I am almost done with the basic design but I am confused on how to make the buttons clickable? One trick could be to make a div for each button but I think there has to be a simple way. Please guide. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="400" style="border:2px solid ;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(0,80);
ctx.lineTo(300,80);
ctx.fillStyle="#333333";
ctx.fillRect(0,320,50,80);

ctx.fillStyle="#333333";
ctx.fillRect(250,320,50,80);
ctx.stroke();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 2):

You can “press” a drawn key on the canvas by listening for mouseclicks and then hittesting whether the click position is inside any one of the calculator key’s boundary.

Here is code that will return true if a mouseclick is inside a rectangle:

```
function isPointInsideRect(pointX,pointY,rectX,rectY,rectWidth,rectHeight){
    return  (rectX <= pointX) && (rectX + rectWidth >= pointX) &&
                 (rectY <= pointY) && (rectY + rectHeight >= pointY);
}
```

If your calculator buttons are round, here is code that will hittest a mouseclick inside a circle:

```
function isPointInsideCircle(pointX,pointY,circleX,circleY,radius){
    var dx=circleX-pointX;
    var dy=circleY-pointY;
    return  ( dx*dx+dy*dy<=radius*radius  );
}
```

Comment: No! Never give me the code. The code might be working very good but its like steroids.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to use an actual image of a calculator, then you could use [HTML map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map) to define where the buttons are.

Updated: [here is an example of map/area in use](http://html.cita.illinois.edu/text/map/map-example.php), similar to the SVG example given elsewhere on this page.

Comment: Yes I had this in mind but it would be a bad programming practice as the load time would decrease.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this method would be classed as bad programming practice. And what do you mean "the load time would decrease"?

Comment: This sounds pretty hacky, like hovering divs around a page. It would require everything to be positioned so that re-sizing did not break the layout. However, if you must use canvas to draw the calculator, it would work.

Comment: There was no mention of resizing the calculator, and even then it could be dealt with pretty undramatically. If you feel it is hacky to use map/area, feel free to tell the W3C, it's a standard that has been around for as long as I can remember and is about as cross-browser as you can get: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/map

Comment: I didn't mean my comment as a slight to you. But I would also point out that using tables for website layout used to be the de-facto standard for W3C. I say this due to the fact that just because something has been around a long time, doesn't mean that it isn't "hacky" by today's standards. With the rapid adoption of HTML5 there ways to elegantly solve problems like this, that used to require a much more inventive approach.

Comment: Also, generating a map can be a painstaking task. That was my main reasoning behind the initial comment.

Comment: No problem. Though the example of tables is different, that was the  misuse/abuse of the "table" element (and its children) to handle layout. In this case there is no misuse of the element "map" (and its children).

Comment: SVG will also be such a similar task, in fact I don't think there is any possible way to get away from writing code (painstaking), even defining "div"s or any kind of elements. Although some methods will require a more or less less coding than others.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SVG if you are looking to bind to graphic elements. The canvas element does not allow binding as its graphics are not considered part of the DOM. See [here](http://www.restingrobot.com/testing/MapDemo.html) for a demo of binding to SVG elements.

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like it is all pure graphics, one thing I’ve done in the past is just listen for where the mouse presses are and check if I’ve clicked inside a button. It’s pretty manual; basically you’d be making your own button/button primitive handling structure.

It would look something like:

```
// define some button objects (can also set the press handlers, etc)
// this should actually be in a Button ‘class’ of some sort
var buttonA = {x: 0, y: 320, width: 50, height: 80};
var buttonB = {x: 250, y: 320, width: 50, height: 80};

//insert some rendering code to draw the buttons based on the button objects above

// and when the mouse has been pressed
function mousePressed(inputEvent){
     // loop in here to check which button has been pressed by going through the button objects and responding as needed
}
canvas.addEventListener(“click”, mousePressed, false);
```

I think it’s basically reinventing the wheel here so I’d check to see if there are existing libraries/frameworks first (I did it this way as a learning exercise).