# how to have a floating icon intercept touch events?

Tags: android, canvas

I want a floating icon on every app or activity. this code works fine, but the whole screen detects the touch, I just want the floating icon to intercept tap, not the whole screen so how do  I do that?

```
public class FloatingButtonService extends Service {
HUDView mView;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "floating button created",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    final Bitmap kangoo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            kangoo.getWidth(), kangoo.getHeight(),
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
    params.setTitle("Load Average");
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    mView = new HUDView(this, kangoo);

    mView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Log.e("kordinatlar",
            // arg1.getX()+":"+arg1.getY()+":"+display.getHeight()+":"+kangoo.getHeight());
            if (arg1.getX() < kangoo.getWidth() & arg1.getY() > 0) {
                Log.d("tıklandı", "touch me");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    wm.addView(mView, params);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}

@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
class HUDView extends ViewGroup {

Bitmap kangoo;

public HUDView(Context context, Bitmap kangoo) {
    super(context);

    this.kangoo = kangoo;

}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // super.onDraw(canvas);

    // delete below line if you want transparent back color, but to
    // understand the sizes use back color
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    canvas.drawBitmap(kangoo, 0, 0, null);

    // canvas.drawText("Hello World", 5, 15, mLoadPaint);

}

protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "touch detected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    // Toast.makeText(getContext(),"onTouchEvent",
    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Try returning "true" in the onTouch  event. That tells the underlying views that the event has been already captured (don't propagate).

Comment: any snippet? thanks

Comment: at the only onTouch function you provided, change "return false" with "return true"

Comment: thanks it works for the icon only now, however, it gets called multiple times. can i specify just one touch event? which is tapping?

Comment: You should check the MotionEvent type, and act accordingly!
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Comment: thanks again. my issue has been resolved now

Comment: I think this is works for you   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826808/how-to-make-a-bitmap-using-canvas-clickable