# Android clickable bitmap image in only java

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

I am trying to make it so when you click this "Play" bitmap it will run other code the thing is i don't know how to check for it.

I tried drawing it as

```
playX = WIDTH / 2;
        playY = HEIGHT / 2;
        Bitmap playButton = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play_button);
        playWidth = playX + playButton.getScaledWidth(canvas);
        playHeight = playY + playButton.getScaledHeight(canvas);
```

Then a touch Event

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getX() > playX && event.getX() < playWidth){
        if(event.getX() > playY && event.getY() < playHeight){
            System.out.println("Button Pushed");
        }
    }}
```

but it doesn't seem to work i dont know if there is a better way to run code when a bitmap is clicked? (I am only using the java class not xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can just use `imageView` to hold the Play image and set `onClickListener` function to have a clickable image.

Something like this:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view_icon);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    System.out.println("Button Pushed");
                }
            });
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned in comments that you are using Canvas drawing, try this instead:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    int x=(int)event.getX();
    int y=(int)event.getY();
    if (drawable.getBounds().contains(x,y)  &&
        event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        System.out.println("Button Pushed");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please refer to this for details [How to make a bitmap using canvas clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826808/how-to-make-a-bitmap-using-canvas-clickable)

Hope this is what you want:)

Comment: So i put this in the MotionEvent method? and there is no "R.id.image_view_icon" ?

Comment: You mean you don't have a xml ImageView for this? Where did you set your  image?

Comment: Its in the res folder in a "drawable-nodpi" folder.

Comment: What is the view that you said "a bitmap is clicked", can you edit your question by putting some code of that?

Comment: Sorry i'm new to Andriod, I don't know what you mean, i draw the bitmap to the screen and i want when that bitmap the "R.drawable.play_button" is clicked on it run certain code

Comment: Im not using the xml file only using the .java to draw to the screen

Comment: Are you sure you are using .java file? Can you post the file? .xml file is used to construct the UI in Android. Check this official doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html.

Comment: All i have is It drawing different bitmaps to the screen, would I have to make my buttons in the xml? Would they render over my other pictures? Oh and it's just a bunch of Cavnas' drawText of drawBitmap methods

Comment: Forgot to say this is for a 2D game not form or anything like that not sure if that changes anything

Comment: Oh dear you are using Canvas, please refer to edited answer above and the link as I am not good in Canvas.

Comment: What is drawable.getBounds()? I don't have anything named drawable (I tried R.drawable and doesn't seem to have getBounds. Sorry if i am missing something obvious

Comment: Try this to get your drawable, `Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_border_grey);`

Comment: Sorry to keep bother you but that doesn't seem to work, this is my code [ http://pastebin.com/3a6jL2ww ] am i doing something wrong? The only thing i am guessing is it can't get the bounds because the drawable isn't connected to the bitmap being drawn but I'm not sure.

Comment: It prints out "I/System.out: Drawable bounds: Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)" am i doing something wrong i tried using your code exactly?

Comment: Can you try with the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826808/how-to-make-a-bitmap-using-canvas-clickable?