# How to make this canvas rectangle clickable?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#9b958c";
ctx.fillRect(sampleRectX, sampleRectY, sampleRectW, sampleRectH);
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctx.fillText("Click here to play again.", sampleTextX, sampleTextY);
```

This rectangle must be clickable. This approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/16455006/3677742 seems to be the answer to my problem, but the event listener for the mouse click just doesn't work and I don't know why. I'm trying to do this:

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

function getClickPosition(e) {
    var xPosition = e.clientX;
    var yPosition = e.clientY;
    if ((sampleRectX <= xPosition) && (sampleRectX + sampleRectW >= xPosition) && (sampleRectY <= yPosition) && (sampleRectY + sampleRectH >= yPosition) {
        if (lose===true) {
            playAgain = true;
        };
    };
};
```

If it is relevant to know, my code is organized like this:

```
//Variables here
...

//Objects (player, enemy...)
...

function main() {
    ...
};

function init() {
    ...
};

function update() {
    ...
};

function draw() {
    ...
    if (gameStarted===true) {
        ...
        if (lose===true) {
            ...
            ctx.fillStyle = "#9b958c";
            ctx.fillRect(sampleRectX, sampleRectY, sampleRectW, sampleRectH);
            ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
            ctx.fillText("Click here to play again.", sampleTextX, sampleTextY);
};

main();
```

I'm a beginner on coding, so I'm sorry if I'm asking something too "noob-level".

Comment: I don't see any event handling in your code. (btw you come from processing background?) :)

Comment: Edited! What do you mean by "processing background"? (I don't know if this is something that I don't know yet or just literally "processing background")

Comment: nevermind, most people I see structure their code and name their functions like this have used processing before, but it's not -such- a unique pattern.

Comment: @barcellosm Whenever you have any JavaScript-related questions, it's usually helpful to throw your code into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can test it out. (or even a simplified version of your code)

Comment: @Jonn Ok, next time I'll do it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((sampleRectX < xPosition) && 
 (sampleRectX + sampleRectW > xPosition) && 
 (sampleRectY < yPosition) && 
 (sampleRectY + sampleRectH > yPosition)
)
```

You got it almost right, you were just missing a parenthesis at the end

If you inspect the mouse event returned from the event listener (which you always should, always inspect everything you get from APIs and see how it works), you'll see there are different values.

You took e.clientX, and so did I, and it didn't work for me because the canvas on my testpage happened not to be located at 0,0 (like it almost always does)

To get the correct values, I had to get `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY`

Shamefully I don't know exactly what each of the individual coordinates on the mouse event stand for, but i'm going to look it up and update my answer.

I hope this time it solves your problem.

If in doubt always debug using console.log() to inspect what's actually happening and what an APIs throw at you.

(If it still doesn't solve your problem put console.log() everywhere in your code where you don't know if it executes and check where it doesn't.)

I made you an example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cxyTV/1/

Comment: Is there a specific place where I should put the event listener or some librarie that I need? I can't find any mistake on the code and still nothing happens.

Comment: Ok another update, this time I tested it, before I claim something wrong again. (no libraries will not solve your bugs, only understanding the problem will)

Comment: I did some tests here and I realize that the event listener isn't recognizing the mouse click. It execute the getClickPosition() even if I don't even touch the mouse (that's why the getClickPosition doesn't work properly, there's no click coordenates to work with).

Comment: Is the jsfiddle I posted not working for you, too? Did you maybe accidentally write `canvas.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition(), false);` ?

Comment: Done! First I needed to change the `canvas.addEventListener` to `document.addEventListener` Only this way it worked properly. Then I had to change the values of the rectangle variables to fixed values - I was using this `var sampleRectX = ((canvas.width*0.5)+((window.innerWidth)*2.85)/100), sampleRectY = ((canvas.height*0.5)+(((window.innerHeight)*28)/100)), sampleRectW = (((window.innerWidth)*23)/100), sampleRectH = (((window.innerHeight)*13)/100);` to make the size and the position of the rectangle responsive. I'll just need to figure out another way to do this responsive stuff now.